# Find the Intersection Point of Two Complex Functions Using Complex3DPlot

Tags: plotting, functions, complex

I want to find the intersection point using `ComplexPlot3D`. I have a function call it $f(\lambda,k)$ ($k$ is fixed) such that at two particular values of $\lambda_{1,2} = \{-1.08862 + 0.886562 i, 1.08862 - 0.886562 i\}$, the values of $f(\lambda_1,k_1)$ and $f(\lambda_2,k_2)$ coalesce.

I want to verify this using `ComplexPlot3D`. I plotted my functions, but everything is red and I don't know how to locate $\lambda_{1,2}$ from the plot. Here is my code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
n = 2; 
exceptional = {-1.08862447826713 + 0.8865616938781102*I, 
1.08862447826713 - 0.8865616938781103*I, -0.421205964382834 + 1.3897935393654808*I, 
0.421205964382834 - 1.3897935393654806*I, -0.421205964382834 - 1.389793539365481*I, 
0.421205964382834 + 1.389793539365481*I, -1.0886244782671313 - 0.8865616938781087*I, 
1.0886244782671313 + 0.8865616938781086*I}; 
quasi[λ_, k_] := (1 + λ^n + 2*λ^(n/2)*Cos[k])^(1/n); 
p1 = 1.666487633682845 + 0.06510032631908054*I; 
p2 = 1.4751050199069482 - 0.06510032631908054*I; 
quasi[exceptional[[1]], p1] == quasi[exceptional[[2]], p2]
{exceptional[[1]], exceptional[[2]]}
ComplexPlot3D[{quasi[λ, p1], quasi[λ, p2]}, {λ, -1.5 - I, 1.5 + I}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

How do I find the intersection points of two complex functions using ComplexPlot3D?

Comment: Translate=move your function so that `p1` is at the origin. Do the same with `p2`. Then `ComplexPlot3D` f1-f2 and hope that shows the origin is the only place where that difference is zero. Place your mouse cursor inside the plot, press and hold the left button and drag to rotate and tilt the plot to see if you can position the plot showing that the origin is the only place where the difference equals zero.

Comment: @ZHENGYAO HUANG: You do not seems to understand what `Complex3DPlot` represents. You can not see any intersection of two complex function on it. You can only see intersection of their absolute values on the plot. But having same absolute value they still can have different argument depicted by color on the plot. So are you willing to see only intersection of their absolute values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define two functions `f1` and `f2` which according to `p1` and `p2` respectively and using `ParametricPlot` to draw the `ReIm` of the complex function `f1` and `f2`.

For two values of `exceptional[[1]]` and `exceptional[[2]]` we draw two points `f1[exceptional[[2]]` and `f2[exceptional[[2]]]`, We found that they are overlay.

```
Clear[f1, f2];
f1[λ_] := quasi[λ, p1];
f2[λ_] := quasi[λ, p2];
plot1 = Block[{λ = x + I*y}, 
   ParametricPlot[ReIm@f1[λ], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive@{Purple, HatchFilling[45  Degree]}]];
plot2 = Block[{λ = x + I*y}, 
   ParametricPlot[ReIm@f2[λ], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive@{Purple, HatchFilling[-45  Degree]}]];
{λ1, λ2} = {exceptional[[1]], exceptional[[2]]};
pt1 = Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point@ReIm@f1@λ1}];
pt2 = Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[20], Opacity[.5], Cyan, 
    Point@ReIm@f2@λ2}];
Show[plot1, plot2, pt1, pt2]
```

[image]

Since

```
Table[With[{boole = 
     quasi[exceptional[[i]], p1] == quasi[exceptional[[j]], p2]}, 
   If[boole, Framed[boole], boole]], {i, Length@exceptional}, {j, 
   Length@exceptional}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

So we can use the same way to check `{λ1, λ2} = {exceptional[[3]], exceptional[[4]]};`  etc. ( see the indexs of `True` )